AWS Eventbridge scheduler day of week valid entries from the console
What are the valid entries for day of week on the Eventbridge scheduler console?  It only accepts "?", all else fails,  I tried 0-6, 1-5, MON-FRI, none are valid.


From the docs for cron expressions in EventBridge:

You can't specify the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields in the same cron expression. If you specify a value or a * (asterisk) in one of the fields, you must use a ? (question mark) in the other.

Your screenshot shows an asterisk in the day of month field, so the only value you can put into the day of the week field is ?
If you didn't specify * as day of month (and put ? instead) then MON-FRI or 1-5 as day of the week would be accepted fine. In other words, if you want to define day of week or day of month parameter, the other one needs to be set to ?.
This is implementation-dependent: some (like actual crontab specs) allow it (and interpret as OR, as in "0 0 12 1 * MON" means "run on any day that is a 1st day of the month OR a Monday), and some (like EventScheduler or quartz expressions) do the "mutually exclusive" thing (if one is specified, the other needs to be ?)

Well I want to schedule every month,  all the days, so that wouldn't make any sense to have a rule that limits you to a specific month, or days,  * in the month field and day of month are valid.  There's no limit in any documentation that I've seen.    In any case, I tried putting in 1 for month, and 1 for day of month, it's still the same issue, can't specify anything other than "?".

Putting one is still "specifying". "Not specifying" means putting ?, which is what you need to put as day of month to be able to specify day of week. Also, the quote I put in the answer is directly from AWS documentation - now you've seen it. It also has a handy example both for "run every day at 10:00" (0 10 * * ? *) and "run Mon through Fri at 18:00" (0 18 ? * MON-FRI *) which you can modify to your liking.

In other words, in eventBridge you can specify (put non-? value) either day of month, or day of week, but not both. It does exclude some specific uses (like "run every Monday, and on the 1st of each month regardless of what the day is"), but you don't seem to have requirements like that. Also, month field has nothing to do with it, we are talking about day of month...

Thank you for the explanation.  What didn't make sense was the use of * and ? being exclusive for day of month and week, otherwise they're used as regular wildcards.   Since they're both explained as wildcards in the table in aws documentation, I used the table data, I see the detailed explanation of the exception rule now,  but the implementation doesn't seem intuitive.   Also the error message not being specific didn't help; could indicate  "Can't use * in Day of Month and Week fields"  etc.  Anyways, I got it working now, thanks for the additional info.

Tbh it kind of makes sense - * is an every wildcard, and ? is any. "Every day of the month, on Mondays" doesn't make a lot of sense, unlike "any day, as long as its Monday". But this is dependent on specific parser, some (like actual linux crontab) allow it and interpret it as "OR" condition (edited that into the answer). Glad you got it solved.

I don't agree. In a special case for the 2 related fields it's not intuitive that you can use * in one and ? in the other, an embedded hidden rule.  This is not an English grammar to be interpreted by a human; it makes sense in an algorithm if you loop everyday of the month and execute on a Monday.  Also, we're talking about console use; command line may have its special built-in structure, but at the console GUI this doesn't make any sense to a user. Seems somebody tried to marry commands to the console.  I think it's poorly implemented, lack of a coherent error message is proof of that.
